# How to configure an external Windows keyboard in OS X?

Tags: windows, macos, keyboard, keyboard-layout

I have an external windows keyboard hooked up to my mac.

```
I want the ALT (Windows) key = COMMAND (Mac) key
I want the CTRL (Windows) key = CONTROL (Mac) key
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open System Preferences -> Keyboard.  Click the Modifier Keys button.  Select the keyboard from the drop down, assign away.

Comment: i dont have the option to assign anything. everything is pre-set in the dropdown menu for the 4 select keys.

Comment: You should be seeing this: http://peelman.us/skitch/keyboard-20101124-133401.jpg

What version of OS X are you running?

Comment: i see that, but how can i chance which key is caps lock? in that example...

Comment: I’m doing just that in the screen shot...

Comment: The labels represent the physical keys. The drop-down lets you choose what key each physical key will act like.